# Hide and show SwiftUI `Table` columns

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-table

I am using SwiftUI's `Table` to generate a table for a macOS app. I would like to be able to hide columns based on `AppStorage` entries. `TableColumnBuilder` doesn't appear to support conditional statements:

```swift
Table(tableData) {
    // This does not work:
    if showColumndA {
        TableColumn("Column A", value: \Row.columnA)
    }
    // Other columns genereated here
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to build a table with SwiftUI where the user can choose what columns to show?

(Showing different tables based on all possible permutations for what columns are visible does not work for my situation)

Comment: It looks like iOS 17 / macOS 14 (currently in beta) can support this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablecolumncustomization

Comment: An ugly hack is to use the .width modifier and set max width to 0 when showColumndA is false. Note that this doesn't entirely hides the columns because there is a small empty space left

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Geoff Hackworth there appears to be a solution for macOS 14 (which was not an option for me at the time of this writing).

I did end up solving my problem by extending `@TableColumnBuilder` to support conditionals (thanks [Swift Lee](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/result-builders/) for your amazing writeup of the `@resultBuilder` API):

```swift
extension TableColumnBuilder {
    static func buildEither<Column>(first column: Column) -> Column
        where
            RowValue == Column.TableRowValue,
            Sort == Column.TableColumnSortComparator,
            Column : TableColumnContent
    {
        column
    }

    static func buildEither<Column>(second column: Column) -> Column
        where
            RowValue == Column.TableRowValue,
            Sort == Column.TableColumnSortComparator,
            Column : TableColumnContent
    {
        column
    }
}
```

The following little example app uses my `@TableColumnBuilder` extension to randomly show either Column A or Column B:

```swift
struct Row: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var columnA: String
    var columnB: String
    var columnC: String

    init(columnA: String, columnB: String, columnC: String) {
        self.id = .init()
        self.columnA = columnA
        self.columnB = columnB
        self.columnC = columnC
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State
    var showColumn: Bool = Bool.random()

    @State
    var rows: [Row] = [
        .init(columnA: "1a", columnB: "1b", columnC: "1c"),
        .init(columnA: "2a", columnB: "2b", columnC: "2c"),
        .init(columnA: "3a", columnB: "3b", columnC: "3c")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Table(rows) {
            if showColumn {
                TableColumn("A", value: \.columnA)
            } else {
                TableColumn("B", value: \.columnB)
            }
            TableColumn("C", value: \.columnC)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this works! Thank you!
But could u help with buildIf for table column builder?
I tried this, but it not works:
   static func buildIf<Column>(_ column: Column?) -> Column?
    where
    RowValue == Column.TableRowValue,
    Column : TableColumnContent
    {
        return column
    }

Comment: But do u know how to make just with if?